# How can we join three tables?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have three tables :

**TABLE1**

```
D_ID    O_COUNT STATUS     P_ID   Q_ID
1          1    close      111    L_1
2          1    Resolved   111    L_1
3          1    close      111    L_1
4          0    open       111    L_1
5          0    new        111    L_1
6          1    close      111    L_1
```

**TABLE2_DL**

```
D_ID    D_LID   C_ID    E_ID    Q_ID    P_ID
  1        11      3      23     L_1    111
  2        12      3      24     L_1    111
  3        13      3      25     L_1    111
  4        14      3      26     L_1    111
  5        15      3      21     L_1    111
```

**TABLE3_TED**

```
EXEC_ID EXEC_STAT   TEAM     C_ID
24      FAILED      Pharma   3
28      FAILED      Pharma1  3
29      FAILED      Pharma   3
25      FAILED      Pharma   3
26      FAILED      Pharma1  3
27      FAILED      Pharma2  3
```

This is the code i've written.

```
select D_ID, D_LID, E_ID,ted.EXEC_STAT,ted.TEAM,
DL.P_ID,DL.Q_ID,ted.C_ID,
(case 
when upper(ted.EXEC_STAT) like 'FAIL%' then 1
else 0
end) as FAILED,
(select O_COUNT from TABLE1 dd
where dd.D_ID = dl.D_ID 
and dd.P_ID=dl.P_ID
and dd.Q_ID=DL.Q_ID) OPENCOUNT,
(select Status from  TABLE1 dd
where dd.d_id = dl.d_id 
and dd.p_id=dl.p_id
and dd.q_id=DL.Q_ID) Status
from TABLE2_DL DL,TABLE3_TED ted
where DL.D_ID in (select d_id from TABLE1 dd
where dd.d_id = dl.d_id 
and dd.p_id=dl.p_id
and dd.q_id=DL.Q_ID
)

and  dl.E_ID = ted.EXEC_ID;
```

Result:

```
2   12  24  FAILED  Pharma  111 L_1 003 1   1   Resolved
3   13  25  FAILED  Pharma  111 L_1 003 1   1   close
4   14  26  FAILED  Pharma1 111 L_1 003 1   0   open
```

this query fetches the records for me. But what i really want is all the records to be fetched from TABLE3_TED and selected records from the other two tables. I tried joining table1 and TABLE2_DL first and aliased that query and then joining that query with TABLE3_TED but i still don't get all the records from TABLE3_TED. Please help.

P.S. I'm new to this portal and i didn't know how to create tables. Can someone please help me with that as well? Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

I might be reading this wrong, but it sounds like you're looking for an `OUTER JOIN`.  Try doing the following:

```
Select      DD.D_Id,
            DD.D_LId,
            DL.E_Id,
            TED.EXEC_STAT,
            TED.TEAM,
            DL.P_Id,
            DL.Q_Id,
            TED.C_Id,
            Case When Upper(TED.EXEC_STAT) Like 'FAIL%'
                Then 1
                Else 0
            End As FAILED,
            T1.O_COUNT As OPENCOUNT,
            T1.Status
From        Table3_TED  TED
Left Join   Table2_DL   DL  On  DL.E_Id = TED.EXEC_Id
Left Join   Table1      DD  On  DD.D_Id = DL.D_Id
                            And DD.P_Id = DL.P_Id
                            And DD.Q_Id = DL.Q_Id
```